# Inserción de múltiples imágenes

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, formularios

Realizo un sistema de auditorias el cual el "auditor" debe de llenar un formulario que consta de preguntas, evidencias (fotografías) y comentarios. El problema radica en que es un cuestionario de 6 o más preguntas por tal motivo **son múltiples inserciones de imágenes a la misma vez**, las cuales necesito que se inserte el nombre de la imagen en su respectivo campo y se almacene en la ruta **complementos/imagenes** para su posterior visualización en mi tabla central.

De antemano agradezco cualquier aporte.

[image: Formulario]

**Código Formulario updlp4.php**

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-udp5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Auditoria</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" id="upd5" name="upd5">
          <div id="result5"></div>

          <input type="hidden" name="valora3_id" id="valora3_id">





          <center>
            <h4><mark>FCAL-127 Checklist LPA Cuarentena</mark></h4>
          </center>
          <center>
            <legend>LPA #4</legend>
          </center>



          <H8>
            <p align="justify">1.- EL ÁREA DE CUARENTENA SE ENCUENTRA CERRADO Y CON RESTRICCIÓN DE ACCESO AL PERSONAL</p>
          </H8>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">RESPUESTA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="RP1" required id="mod_RP1">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                <option value="SI">SI</option>
                <option value="NO">NO</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>








          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">EVIDENCIA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="file" capture="camera" name="file" id="mod_EP1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></input>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">COMENTARIOS
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <textarea name="CP1" id="mod_CP1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="COMENTARIOS" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />
          <br />









          <H8>2.- TODO EL MATERIAL ESTÁ IDENTIFICADO CON FCAL-124 ETIQUETA, IDENTIFICANDO EL MOTIVO DE RECHAZO</H8>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">RESPUESTA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="RP2" required id="mod_RP2">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                <option value="SI">SI</option>
                <option value="NO">NO</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>




          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">EVIDENCIA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="file" capture="camera" name="file" id="mod_EP2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></input>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">COMENTARIOS<span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <textarea name="CP2" id="mod_CP2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="COMENTARIOS" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />
          <br />





          <H8>3.- EL MATERIAL FÍSICO EN CUARENTENA ESTÁ REGISTRADO EN FCAL-47 INVENTARIO DE CUARENTENA</H8>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">RESPUESTA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="RP3" required id="mod_RP3">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                <option value="SI">SI</option>
                <option value="NO">NO</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">EVIDENCIA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="file" capture="camera" name="file" id="mod_EP3" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></input>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">COMENTARIOS<span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <textarea name="CP3" id="mod_CP3" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="COMENTARIOS" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />
          <br />


          <H8>
            <p align="justify">4.- "EL MATERIAL FÍSICO EN CUARENTENA CUMPLE CON EL TIEMPO MÁXIMO DE ALMACENAJE:40 DÍAS DE MATERIAL EN PROCESO Y/O PRODUCTO TERMINADO. PARA MATERIAL DE PROVEEDORES MÁXIMO 30 DÍAS PARA PROVEEDORES INTERNACIONALES Y MÁXIMO 5 DÍAS PROVEEDORES
              NACIONALES."
            </p>
          </H8>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">RESPUESTA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="RP4" required id="mod_RP4">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                <option value="SI">SI</option>
                <option value="NO">NO</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">EVIDENCIA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="file" capture="camera" name="file" id="mod_EP4" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></input>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">COMENTARIOS
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <textarea name="CP4" id="mod_CP4" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="COMENTARIOS" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />
          <br />





          <H8>5.- LA CANTIDAD FÍSICA COINCIDE CON LA CANTIDAD EN EL SISTEMA AX</H8>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">RESPUESTA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="RP5" required id="mod_RP5">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                <option value="SI">SI</option>
                <option value="NO">NO</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">EVIDENCIA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="file" capture="camera" name="file" id="mod_EP5" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></input>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">COMENTARIOS
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <textarea name="CP5" id="mod_CP5" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="COMENTARIOS" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />
          <br />





          <H8>6.- EL REGISTRO FCAL-47 INVENTARIO DE CUARENTENA TIENE TODOS LOS CAMPOS LLENOS</H8>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">RESPUESTA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="RP6" required id="mod_RP6">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                <option value="SI">SI</option>
                <option value="NO">NO</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">EVIDENCIA
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="file" capture="camera" name="file" id="mod_EP6" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></input>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">COMENTARIOS
                            </label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <textarea name="CP6" id="mod_CP6" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="COMENTARIOS" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />
          <br />






          <div class="ln_solid"></div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
              <button id="upd_data5" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
            </div>
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->






< script >
  $(function() {
    $("input[name='file']").on("change", function() {
      var formData = new FormData($("#result5")[0]);
      var ruta = "action/updlpa4.php";
      $.ajax({
        url: ruta,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(datos) {
          $("#respuesta").html(datos);
        }
      });
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

**Código de insercción updlpa4.php**

```html
<?php    
include "../config/config.php";

if (isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
    
    $RP1 = $_POST["RP1"];
    $EP1 = $_POST["EP1"];       
    $CP1 = $_POST["CP1"];   
    $RP2 = $_POST["RP2"];
    $EP2 = $_POST["EP2"];       
    $CP2 = $_POST["CP2"];
    $RP3 = $_POST["RP3"];
    $EP3 = $_POST["EP3"];       
    $CP3 = $_POST["CP3"];   
    $RP4 = $_POST["RP4"];
    $EP4 = $_POST["EP4"];       
    $CP4 = $_POST["CP4"];
    $RP5 = $_POST["RP5"];
    $EP5 = $_POST["EP5"];       
    $CP5 = $_POST["CP5"];
    $RP6 = $_POST["RP6"];
    $EP6 = $_POST["EP6"];       
    $CP6 = $_POST["CP6"];
    
    
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    $name = $file["name"];
    $type = $file["type"];
    $tmp_n = $file["tmp_name"];
    $size = $file["size"];
    $folder = "../complementos/lpa/";
    $id=$_POST['valora2_id'];
    
    if ($type != 'image/jpg' && $type != 'image/jpeg' && $type != 'image/png' && $type != 'image/gif')
    {
      echo "Error, el archivo no es una imagen"; 
    }
    else if ($size > 1024*1024)
    {
      echo "Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB";
    }
    else
    {
        $src = $folder.$name;
       @move_uploaded_file($tmp_n, $src);

       $query=mysqli_query($con, 
       "UPDATE 
       
       lpa4 
       
       set 
       
       RP1=\"$RP1\",
       EP1=\"$EP1\",
       CP1=\"$CP1\",
       RP2=\"$RP2\",
       EP2=\"$EP2\",
       CP2=\"$CP2\",
       RP3=\"$RP3\",
       EP3=\"$EP3\",
       CP3=\"$CP3\",
       RP4=\"$RP4\",
       EP4=\"$EP4\",
       CP4=\"$CP4\",
       RP5=\"$RP5\",
       EP5=\"$EP5\",
       CP5=\"$CP5\",
       RP6=\"$RP6\",
       EP6=\"$EP6\",
       CP6=\"$CP6\"
       
       
       
       where id=$id");
       
       
       
       //if($query){
        //echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
            //<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
            //<strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong> Insercción de auditoria correcta
        //</div>";
      // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas haciendo referencia a
`$file = $_FILES["file"];` en  updlpa4.php

y a `$("input[name='file']").on("change",...`  en el principal, 

pero no tienes ningún `<input type="file" name="file">`

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios @Fly, ya realice la modificación del código pero sigue sin realizar la inserción de las imágenes.

Comment: ¿En qué punto de tu código está el problema exactamente luego de haber hecho las depuraciones de lugar (verificar que los datos llegan desde el cliente, verificar errores de conexión/inserción, etc)?